# WordPress posts with featured images and categories

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am looking for a solution for:

```
SELECT ID
     , post_date_gmt
     , post_content
     , post_title
     , post_modified_gmt 
  FROM wphj_posts 
 WHERE post_status = 'publish'
```

and:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value
              , post_id
              , meta_id
           FROM wphj_postmeta
          WHERE meta_key LIKE '_wp_attached_file'
          ORDER 
             BY meta_value ASC
```

What I did first was this, which doesn't work as I want it to:

```
SELECT ID
     , post_date_gmt
     , post_content
     , post_title
     , post_modified_gmt
     , meta_value 
  FROM wphj_posts
     , wphj_postmeta 
 WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
   AND meta_key LIKE '_wp_attached_file'
```

Am simply trying to query WordPress database to get post data from `wp_posts` and the featured image of the same post from the `wp_postmeta` table.

Stuff I tried to do: used union, unionall, join on, inner join, left join. Unfortunately they don't work.

Update, came up with this using wpDatatables plugin, works on the plugin dashboard but not as a query on its own :\ - what am i doing wrong folks

```
   SELECT posts_post.ID AS post_ID,
   posts_post.post_date_gmt AS post_post_date_gmt,
   posts_post.post_title AS post_post_title,
   CONCAT('<a href="',posts_post.guid,'">',posts_post.post_title,'</a>') AS post_title_with_link_to_post,
   posts_post.post_content AS post_post_content,
   posts_post.post_status AS post_post_status,
   posts_post.post_name AS post_post_name,
   CONCAT(
                                '<a href="',
                                posts_post.guid,
                                '"><img src="', 
                                REPLACE( 
                                    posts_post_img.guid,
                                    CONCAT(
                                        '.',
                                        SUBSTRING_INDEX(  
                                            posts_post_img.guid,
                                            '.',
                                            -1
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    CONCAT(
                                        '-150x150.' ,
                                        SUBSTRING_INDEX(  
                                            posts_post_img.guid,
                                            '.',
                                            -1
                                        )
                                    )
                                    ), 
                                '" /></a>'
                              ) AS post_thumbnail_with_link_to_post,
   post_taxonomy_category_tbl.name AS post_taxonomy_category
FROM wphj_posts AS posts_post
INNER JOIN (SELECT name, object_id as id FROM wphj_terms AS post_taxonomy_category_tbl_terms INNER JOIN wphj_term_taxonomy AS post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy ON post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_id = post_taxonomy_category_tbl_terms.term_id  AND post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' INNER JOIN wphj_term_relationships AS rel_post_taxonomy_category_tbl  ON post_taxonomy_category_tbl_termtaxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = rel_post_taxonomy_category_tbl.term_taxonomy_id) AS post_taxonomy_category_tbl
 ON post_taxonomy_category_tbl.ID = posts_post.id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT posts_post_imgposts.guid AS guid, posts_post_imgpostmeta.post_id AS post_id
                                    FROM wphj_postmeta AS posts_post_imgpostmeta 
                                    INNER JOIN wphj_posts AS posts_post_imgposts 
                                        ON posts_post_imgpostmeta.meta_value = posts_post_imgposts.ID
                                    WHERE posts_post_imgpostmeta.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' ) AS posts_post_img
 ON posts_post_img.post_id = posts_post.ID
WHERE 1=1 
AND posts_post.post_type = 'post'
```

Comment: I think you need to sit down with a basic introductory book or tutorial on relational databases.

Comment: my question said clearly that i couldn't get my head around the best/correct way to do this and now its kind off shut, i keep on refreshing this page hoping for an answer Strawberry. if you would be kind enough and provide me with one since you already went through many books on the subject, i know its probably against the rules to be ask to be spoon-fed am just overwhelmed and can't even think anymore :(

Comment: Just relax. Take a break, and come back to it when you feel reenergised.

Comment: can't afford to take a break sadly, here is what i came up with so far using the wpDatatables plugin - it shows the desired output on the plugin dashboard yet when i use the same query to get JSON output it shows a blank page

Comment: Well, maybe see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: very informative, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I ran it in sequal pro on on of my local installations, and I got the it to work as I think you would like it to work.

```
SELECT ID,
  post_date_gmt,
  post_content,
  post_title,
  post_modified_gmt,
  meta_value
FROM wphj_posts, wphj_postmeta
WHERE wphj_posts.ID = wphj_postmeta.post_id
AND wphj_postmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
AND wphj_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```